# Структуры и работа с файлами

Tags: c, файлы

Доброго времени суток. У меня не получается разобрать строку вида:

```
4273 Багров Д. С. 5454 знззз 
4273 Нуйикн А. А. 4322 нзнзз 
4273 Иванов А. А. 3434 ннззз 
4272 Козлов И. И. 4243 ззззз
```

И получить из нее фамилию студента как строку и оценки, как числа (запись вида: Багров Д. С. 5454). Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать правильно.

Загвоздка в функции debt().

Собственно, код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student {
  char group[5];
  char fio[21];
  int ekz[5];
  char zach[7];
};

void debt();

int main() {
  FILE *input;
  int choice;

  input = fopen("students.txt", "r");

  if (input == NULL) {
    puts("Файл students.txt не найден");
    getchar();
    return 1;
  }

  do {
    puts("\nВыберите номер пункта меню:");
    puts("1 - Вывод списка студентов, имеющих задолженности");
    puts("2 – Вывод списка среднего балла каждого студента");
    puts("3 – Вывод списка среднего балла всей группы");
    puts("4 - Выход\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice) {
      case 1:
        debt(input);
        break;
      case 4:
        break;
      default:
        puts("\nНужно вводить номер пункта от 1 до 4");
        break;
    }
  }

  while (choice != 4);
  fclose(input);
  return 0;
}

void debt(FILE *input) {
  struct student this;

  while (fgets(this.ekz, sizeof(this), input) != NULL) {
    printf("%d\n", this.ekz);
  }

  fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: @vox решение "в лоб": разобрать посимвольно, пропустить первое слово из цифр, пропустить пробел, записать позицию, найти следующую цифры, записать позицию конца фамилии, посимвольно разобрать слово из цифр. Цифровые символы легко преобразовать в числа, отнимая у них символ нуля: `int number = s[i] - '0';`  
можно еще разбить с помощью `strtok()`, но пробелы в имени-фамилии несколько усложнят задачу. Можно прибегнуть к регэкспам, в си с ними сложно работать, но здесь нет сложных конструкций.

Comment: @vox, для начала прочтите `man fgets`.

Эта функция читае **строку**, а не `int`. Для заполнения полей структуры посмотрите на `man sscanf` (для чтения полей из строки в  структуру).

Вообще-то формат данных у Вас не очень удобный. Возни много будет.

Затем, задумайтесь, как передать из `debt()` прочитанные данные (видимо много структур). Например,  такая `debt()` вернет массив (который надо будет делать в ней)

    struct student *debt (FILE *in, int *array_size);

Comment: Чтение из строки в поля структуры у Вас получится многословным. Без проверок на ошибки, что-то в таком духе.

      char str[LINE_MAX];
      while (fgets(str, LINE_MAX, in)) {
         char i[3], o[3], g[6];
         struct student t;
         if (sscanf(str, "%4s %12s %2s %2s %5s %6s", 
               t.group, t.fio, i, o, g, t.zach) != 6) {
            puts("format error"); continue;
         }
         snprintf(t.fio, 21, "%s %s %s", t.fio, i, o);
         int j;
         for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
           t.ekz[j] = isdigit(g[j])) ? g[j] - '0' : 0;
        ... 


места мало....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Считывайте код цифры и отнимайте от него код символа ноль

```
  void student_average_scope(FILE *input) {
    struct student this;
    int i, sum, j = 4;

    while (fgets((char *)&this, sizeof(this), input) != NULL) {
      for (i = 0, sum = 0; i < j; i++)
        sum = this.ekz[i] - '0';

    this.fio[20] = '\0';
    this.ekz[4] = '\0';
    printf("%s - %s\n", this.fio, this.ekz);
  }

  fclose(input);
}
```

Comment: @parkov, если внимательно посмотрите на описание struct student в тексте вопроса, то с огорчением обнаружите, что тип элементов массива `ekz[]` в структуре это **int**.

Про всякое отсутствие даже попытки проверить формат данных в файле я уже молчу.

--

Поразительна вера автора вопроса, принявшего этот код (наверняка ведь не тестировал), в квалификации отвечающих.

Comment: @avp, int, естественно, необходимо заменить на char. То, что в вопросе тип элемента ekz int - яно не является обязательным условием.

Comment: А также надо заставить пользователя обязательно вводить данные в фиксированном формате и не путать цифры с буквами.

Comment: Да, на входе заранее утвержденный формат вида 4273 Багров Д. С. 5454 знззз 
Да, он будет именно такой: номер группы, Фамилия студента, оценки, зачеты

Comment: @vox, но ведь *длина* фамилии у разных студентов может быть разная.

Следовательно смещение оценок и зачетов от начала строки тоже будет разной.

Или Вы хотите заставить оператора данных высчитывать правильное количество пробелов после инициалов?

Comment: @avp согласен, но я задал вопрос о том, как считать числа вместе с фамилией. меня устраивает ответ (прошу заметить, единственный ответ), но если считаете, что ответ не полный - можете дополнить его, я буду только рад и награжу очками.

Comment: @vox, комментарии еще от 4 апреля прям под вопросом.